# Pegar valores array de um formulário com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou precisando pegar os valores marcados com PHP, porém não estou conseguindo. Veja abaixo:

```
....
$c = 1;
$visualizar = '<table class="table table-hover">';
while($peMaterias = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlMaterias)){
    $visualizar .= "<tr>";
    $visualizar .= "<td><i class=\"fas fa-caret-right\"></i> <span style='font-weight: bold'>Usuário ".$c."</span></td>";
    $visualizar .= "<td><div class='radio-group'>
      <label class='radio-label'>
          <input name='Licenca[".$c."]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
          <span class='inner-label' style='color: #008000; font-weight: bold'>Fuma</span>
      </label>";
      $visualizar .= "<td><label class='radio-label'>
          <input name='Licenca[".$c."]' type='checkbox' value='1' >
          <span class='inner-label' style='color: #F00; font-weight: bold'>Bebe</span>
      </label>";
      $visualizar .= "<td><label class='radio-label'>
      <input name='Licenca[".$c."]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
      <span class='inner-label' style='color: #008000; font-weight: bold'>Trabalha</span>
  </label>";
  $visualizar .= "<td><label class='radio-label'>
      <input name='Licenca[".$c."]' type='checkbox' value='1'  >
      <span class='inner-label' style='color: #F00; font-weight: bold'>PcD</span>
  </label>
</div></td></tr>";
$c++;
}
```

E estou tentando dessa forma:

```
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Salvar"){
   for($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST["Licenca"]); $i++)
  {
    echo $_POST["Licenca"][$i]."<br>";
  }
}
```

Porém está me retornando apenas:

```
1
1
```

Tentei também dessa forma:

```
 for($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST["Licenca"]); $i++)
  {
    $verdadeira[$i] = ($_POST["Licenca"][$i] == 1)?"S":"N";
    echo $verdadeira[$i]."<br>";
  }
```

Mas retorna assim:

```
N
S
S
```

Comment: Já fez o debug do código para saber exatamente qual é o array `$_POST`? Poste-o na pergunta, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está gerando o array da forma errada do que você pretende.

Aqui..

```
Licenca[".$c."]
```

.. em todos o checkbox, não importa qual será escolhido, sempre será igual!

O que você pode fazer é isso:

```
Licenca[".$c."][]
```

Para inserir uma outra dimensão com os valores que você vai usar. Ou até mesmo assim:

```
Licenca[".$c."][fuma]
```

Inserindo a chave que você quer resgatar que contém o valor:

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$visualizar .= "<td><div class='radio-group'>
      <label class='radio-label'>
          <input name='Licenca[".$c."][fuma]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
          <span class='inner-label' style='color: #008000; font-weight: bold'>Fuma</span>
      </label>";
      $visualizar .= "<td><label class='radio-label'>
          <input name='Licenca[".$c."][bebe]' type='checkbox' value='1' >
          <span class='inner-label' style='color: #F00; font-weight: bold'>Bebe</span>
      </label>";
      $visualizar .= "<td><label class='radio-label'>
      <input name='Licenca[".$c."][trabalha]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
      <span class='inner-label' style='color: #008000; font-weight: bold'>Trabalha</span>
  </label>";
  $visualizar .= "<td><label class='radio-label'>
      <input name='Licenca[".$c."][PcD]' type='checkbox' value='1'  >
      <span class='inner-label' style='color: #F00; font-weight: bold'>PcD</span>
  </label>
```

Depois você pode resgata-los assim:

```
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST["Licenca"]); $i++)
      {
        foreach($_POST["Licenca"][$i] as $key => $value){
            echo $key . " - " . $value . " | ";
        }
        echo "<br>";
      }
```

Comment: Tem razão Andrei. Não me atentei a esse detalhe. Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fox.11 tranquilo ... Abraço! =)